# Grand Totals in HighCharts Pie Chart Legend

Tags: jquery, highcharts, legend-properties

Is there a way for me to get a grand total at the end of my value column in my legend?  Here is the code for my legend right here as well as the fiddle wtih it broken into two columns for the name and value of the data[] set.

```
legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            width: 220,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true,
            labelFormatter: function() {
                return '<div style="width:200px"><span style="float:left">' + this.name + '</span><span style="float:right">' + this.y + '%</span></div>';
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Primary',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        }
```

id like the column to be something like this

```
Data1      2
Data2      3
Data3      2
         ---
           7
```

What I need to be able to do is add the dashed or preferrably solid line underneath that row and then the grand total of all of the data values.  Here is my current fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/29/

thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could hack this in by appending the total to the last legend item.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function(event) {
      $('.highcharts-legend-item').last().append('<br/><div style="width:200px"><hr/> <span style="float:left"> Total </span><span style="float:right"> ' + total + '</span> </div>')
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/31/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! i'm just learning highcharts and the API is kind of lengthy so i haven't been able to figure this stuff out!

Comment: Is there a reason i'd be receiving the error of SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'last' when using chrome and/or IE 7,8,9,10.  It works fine in the fiddle but doesn't work in my site itself.  Odd, but again thank you this is certainly what i'm lookign for

Comment: Hmm, not sure, what version of JQuery are you using?  What is the error in Chrome?  `Script438` is an IE thing and I don't trust IE to throw a meaningful error.

Comment: my reference was wrong earlier, i meant to mark your answer again i've been busy sorry abotu that, thanks for checking back in to help out!

Comment: btw, it seems `useHTML: true,` in legend section is important for this solution

Comment: Why its `100.02` in Total...Fingers will arise on Highcharts if this inaccuracy will occur on Stock Exchange Charts...which mean .01 will be a great great value

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena, [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 5):

I would actually add the total as another entry in the data array, with a null value and a label attribute. Something like this:

```
legend: {
    labelFormatter: function() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.y_label;
    },
},
// ...
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    data: [
        {'name': 'Real Estate', 'y': 12.55, 'y_label': 12.55},
        // ...
        {'name': 'Total', 'y': null, 'y_label': 100, 'color': 'transparent'}
    ]
}]
```

[image: example]

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Aeon/9cZKg/1/